# How to connect to mongo shell from windows cmd?

Tags: windows, mongodb, cmd, mongo-shell

This is my first time using Mongodb, It connect normally using the IDE from Mongodb university basics m001 course but when I tried to connect from cmd it won't connect and gives me this error

> *** You have failed to connect to a MongoDB Atlas cluster. Please ensure that your IP whitelist allows connections from your network.
> Error: Authentication failed. :
> connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17 @(connect):2:6 exception:
> connect failed exiting with code 1

I added the path to my environment & checked the network access from my Atlas and I can connect to it from anywhere

Can anyone help me with this please??